# xls to csv automate

Tags: vbscript

I'm using a script that takes all the xls files in a directory and saves them as a CSV file.  I wanted to try and add two modifications to it but not sure how.

First, I'd like to select the save directory as it currently just saves in the workingdir.

Second, I'd like to delete the xls file at the end.  I would be ok with this not happening.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
WorkingDir = "C:\test\excel"
Extension = ".XLS"

Dim fso, myFolder, fileColl, aFile, FileName, SaveName
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
Set myFolder = fso.GetFolder(WorkingDir)
Set fileColl = myFolder.Files

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each aFile In fileColl
    ext = Right(aFile.Name,4)
    If UCase(ext) = UCase(extension) Then
        'open excel
        FileName = Left(aFile,InStrRev(aFile,"."))
        Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(aFile)
        SaveName = FileName & "csv"
        objWorkbook.SaveAs SaveName, 23
        objWorkbook.Close 
    End If
Next

Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
Set fileColl = Nothing
```

Comment: SO is not a place where we do your work for you. What have you tried so far, and what specific problem do you need help with? Did you do any research at all? (both features you're trying to add are rather well-documented)

Comment: I understand.  I have searched a ton of forums, but havent found a variant to do what I want.  I dont know how to change the working directory.  Do I insert myFolder = "c:\savetodirectory" before the SaveName line?  Do you know the command that I can research?

Comment: I looked at the objworkbook.saveas variants, but didnt see anything to select file path.  I've tried adding a WorkingDir2 at the top and calling that directory with Set myFolder = fso.GetFolder(WorkingDir2).  I put this right above the savename line.   If I hadnt given this 2-3 hours of work i wouldnt be here.

Comment: [stackoverflow://\[vbscript\]+choose+folder](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[vbscript]+choose+folder)

Comment: yes, i've done numerous searches for this already.  I just went through 3 pages of that and saw nothing I could apply.

Comment: I'm making progress.   I am having trouble pulling the filename in though.  I name the directory and want to use the Save name variable.  I am getting a objWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Jason" & SaveName, 23

Comment: Updated Code.  I added a savedir dim.  Defined the path.  I want to reuse the filename with the new path.  It keeps telling me path doesnt exist or invalid filename.  Not sure why.                                                                                                 

SaveName = savedir & FileName 
objsave.SaveAs SaveName, 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Wezel: Please find the code which I change a bit below for your requirement below(The changes which I have done is commented in the name of changed after REM.). The Filename variable which is present is already with the entire path and the mistake which you did is trying to concatenate the a new path with the old one and result the value like this "C:\test\csv\C:\test\excel\samplefile1.xls". So it is throwing a error that path not found. In addition to this I have added a code for your second requirement. Kindly let me know if it works

```
`WorkingDir = "C:\Test\Excel"
savedir="C:\Test\"     REM changed 
Extension = ".xls"

Dim fso, myFolder, fileColl, aFile, FileName, SaveName
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
Set myFolder = fso.GetFolder(WorkingDir)
Set fileColl = myFolder.Files

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each aFile In fileColl
   ext = Right(aFile.Name,4)
   name= Left(aFile.Name,Len(aFile.Name)-3)         REM changed 
   If UCase(ext) = UCase(extension) Then
    'open excel
    FileName = Left(aFile,InStrRev(aFile,"."))
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(aFile)
    SaveName = savedir & name & "csv"            REM changed 
    objWorkbook.SaveAs SaveName, 23
    objWorkbook.Close 
   End If
Next
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
Set fileColl = Nothing
fso.DeleteFile(WorkingDir&"\*"&Extension) REM changed
Set fso = Nothing`
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  The file removal is working great, but the path isnt working quite right.  The last folder isnt opening, but rather using it in the filename and it adds double period to the extension "..csv" when saving the file. eg.  C:\Users\U465205\Desktop\alpa_execution\saveexcelfile..csv

Comment: Can you please elaborate where the issue is as I have tested the same in my local and works fine. The file path which I have given is an example. You have to use your own path where the file should be saved...

Comment: Actually the path is working fine, but it still appending the last folder directory to the file name.

Comment: Correct, lets say my working dir is "C:\Test\Excel\" and my savedir is "C:\Test\".  If i have an excel file in the working dir called myfile.xls and run the script the output in the savedir is testmyfile..csv not sure what else i can say to help.

Comment: So, i setup my directories over and its all working.  Sorry, for the confusion!  Thanks for your assistance!